# raspberry raspbian kernel downgrade to 3.2.x

Tags: raspbian

I need to install kernel raspbian 3.2.27. I am newbie with linux and rpi. (I need test old drivers) Could you please help me how to downgrade to 3.2.27?

I know how to upgrade with apt-get upgrade but I have no idea how to downgrade? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out solution - just need to download older version of raspbian, format sd card and put the old version with win32diskimager on formatted card. :)

Comment: You do know that you can mark this as a self-answer, correct?